# How to return typed mutable array from Swift to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift

In Objective-C I use generics and like them a lot, in swift I want to use  Array but in Objective-C its accessible only as a Array, so it looks like I need to return NSMutableArray while losing type signature that Swift doesn't support? 
Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Show some relevant Objective-C and Swift code and show what you need to be different.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, `NSMutableArray` doesn't support generics. Also in Swift, we avoid passing mutable data between methods. So the best approach is to do this in Swift to maintain your type information:

```
@objc
func someArray() -> [String] {
    return ["Hello"]
}
```

And then make a mutable copy in Objective-C:

```
NSArray<NSString *> *array = [someClass someArray];
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
[mutableArray addObject:@"Hello again!"];
```

Comment: Well if I want to access MutableArray its because I want to add values to it or remove them... to that original array in that other class... 

You say: "Also in Swift, we avoid passing mutable data between methods."  

 Between classes you want to say ?   So ok, its just not possible, thats it... Swift is pain in my ass , long life kotlin :P

Comment: @Renetik `NSMutableArray` is still accessible in Swift. You absolutely *need* an array with reference semantics, you still have access to it. But unconstrained shared mutable state like this, is ***really bad practice***, *in any language*. There's a reason why `Array` is a value type. Embrace that in your design. If you give me more context as to why you need to share this array, i can try to provide some suggestions.

Comment: @Alexander thank you, but I don't share your opinion about bad practice in this case. Never mind I did it how it was supposed to force me to do in the end I think.

Comment: @Renetik The problem is that unconstrained shared mutable state breaks your codes invariants. Whoever has access to this array can mess with it in ways your program doesn't intend. "Well I'm the one accessing the array, so I won't mess it up." That's not the case. Good design eliminates bugs not by not creating them, but by creating circumstances in which bugs *literally cannot occur*. See for example, the use of `Optional` (without force unwrapping) to fix null pointer errors. You literally *cannot* run into such an error, so long as you don't use force unwraps.

Comment: @Renetik In some language with nullable-by-default-references (e.g. C#, Java, Python, Ruby) you might say "Well this *might* be `null`, but that's fine, because I made sure never ends up here, so it's safe". *No it's not*. You could have made a mistake in your reasoning, or you could be correct but accidentally introduce a bug in the future when you've forgotten about the intricacies of that section of code. `Optional` completely eliminates this class of error, not because it "happens to be correct" today, but because it literally cannot happen (now, or in the future).

Comment: @Renetik Similarly, your application would benefit by having well defined interfaces that expose only the sane set of operations. What happens if a consumer takes your array and adds `NSMutableArray<ForumCategoryData>`, loads it in a Objective C module, casts it to `NSMutableArray`, and adds a `KittenData` to it? How will your code respond? Will it break? Is this an edge case you'll add in your unit test (because you should)? Yet it's a class of error that could be completed rendered impossible by using other techniques

Comment: @Renetik In other words, adding constraints to your systems so that they can only do those actions which "make sense" removes the opportunity for errors.

Comment: @Renetik One last thing: Shared mutable state (lets call it SMS) *complicates* design. Because whenever you have code that operates on this array, you cannot think about it in isolation (which also means it can be tricky to unit test), because the local behaviour can be influenced by foreign entities holding a reference to your array. The only way to have a full understanding of one usage of this SMS, is by first fully understanding *all usages* of this SMS. That's *hard*.  Plus, you're breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up making it like this

```
@objc lazy var categories: Array<ForumCategoryData> = []

@objc func add(category: ForumCategoryData) {
    categories.append(category)
}
```

because interoperability with objective c makes other problems in closures if you return NSMutableArray... I just try to write as clean code as possible and with mixed swift/objective-c its pure war.

Comment: I think this approach is cleaner .  The Swift/Obj-C bridge adds a lot of complexity. I think it is helpful when you are migrating code or when you can’t do something in Swift. But it’s definitely an easier time to pick one language or the other if possible.

Comment: Well, sure, but nobody will pay me time to rewrite whole app... In need to improvise.